# Magento 2: Apply visibility and status filters on product collection

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I want to apply visibility and status filter on product collection. Like in Magento 1 we do:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

I get the product collection in Magento 2 but not find function to apply above filters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For getting product collection with status enable and visibility:

you have to keep below code in block file.

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;
protected $productVisibility;
protected $productStatus;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
    $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    return $collection;
}
```

Above code working for visibility type for:

- **VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH**
- **VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG**
- **VISIBILITY_BOTH**

Comment: I have implemented in a similar way @Rakesh, i need to get the results of the products as per the filters applied, but products are not rendering as per the filters...need help here...   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136959/function-which-triggers-the-filterable-attributes-in-magento2

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya Is there any way to display "not visible individually" Products in product list page

Comment: How do I add the filters to `SearchCriteriaBuilder` when using `ProductRepositoryInterface`? (See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84347/60128.)

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
    $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
```

Used classes are:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $collectionFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
 */
protected $productStatus;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
 */
protected $productVisibility;
```

Review these classes to check another methods to get possible status or visibility values.

However, review concept of repositories, as far as I saw Magento 2 recommends using repository to access product data instead of using collection. For example:

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

$products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

Comment: Hi , could check if my question is similar to this and i have to use the searchCriteria? I had try it too but it breaks all.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117112/set-visibility-status-to-product-magento-2-error

Answer (score 2):

for product collection with status enable and visibility:

you can try with below code

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;
protected $productVisibility;
protected $productStatus;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
    $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
    return $collection;
}
```

for this code working for visibility type like :

```
VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
VISIBILITY_BOTH
```