# Magento 2: How to set visibility and status to product using collection?

Tags: magento2, module, attributes, collection

I'm creating a cron to pass through all the products and set them visible and active.

This is my execute of the cron who runs well:

```
public function execute(){
    /**
     * @var $item \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     */

    $items = $this->productCollection->getItems();

    foreach($items as $item){
        echo  $item->getSku() .'<br>';
        $item->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $item->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $item->save();
    }
    echo 'finish';
}
```

I've got a product with none **visibility** and **status** disabled, but when I run the function the product is still with none visibility and status disabled.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the  **$item->save();** with below code:

```
$item->getResource()->saveAttribute($item, 'visibility');

$item->getResource()->saveAttribute($item, 'status');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the **Collection** and set the **AreaCode**, I've created something similar and works.

```
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class EAVMassUpdateCommand extends Command
{
public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct();
}

...

public function execute(){

    $items = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();

    foreach($items as $item){
        echo  $item->getSku() .'<br>';
        $item->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $item->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $item->save();
    }
    echo 'finish';
}
```

> **Visibility Type:**

```
VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE =>  1

VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG =>  2

VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH =>  3

VISIBILITY_BOTH =>  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection  $productCollection
) {
    ......
    $this->productRepository = $productRepositoryInterface;
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute(){
$items = $this->productCollection->getItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    $productId =  $item->getEntityId();
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    $product->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $this->productRepository->save($product);     
}
    echo 'finish';
}
```

> **Visibility Type:**

```
VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE =>  1

VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG =>  2

VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH =>  3

VISIBILITY_BOTH =>  4
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting product collection with status enable and visibility:

you have to keep below code in block file.

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
    array $data = []
)
{

    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', ['eq' => '20']);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
    $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

    return $collection;
}
```

Above code working for visibility type for:

- VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
- VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
- VISIBILITY_BOTH