# How do you filter out Not Visible Individually products from bestsellers?

Tags: magento2, filter

I'm using the following to get a list of bestselling products:

```
$collection = $this->_resourceFactory->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection');
```

However, this includes products with a visibility of Not Visible Individually. I've tried to filter them out by using the following:

```
$collection->join('catalog_category_product_index', 'catalog_category_product_index.product_id = entity_id', '')->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE));
```

But this gives a `Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous` error due to the `(store_id IN(0)) AND (store_id IN(0))` condition added by `Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection::_applyStoresFilterToSelect()`.

Could anyone explain how I can add the table name to the `store_id` column in that filter – or a better way for me to filter out Not Visible Individually products from the bestsellers list?

Comment: See [this answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91892/43565).

Comment: `setVisibility` is an undefined method (as is `addAttributeToFilter`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to copy the

```
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection
```

class into

```
code/Vendor/MagentoSales/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php
```

and make the following changes:

```
namespace Vendor\MagentoSales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

  /**
   * Apply stores filter to select object
   *
   * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select
   * @return $this
   */
  protected function _applyStoresFilterToSelect(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select)
  {
      $nullCheck = false;
      $storeIds = $this->_storesIds;

      if (!is_array($storeIds)) {
          $storeIds = [$storeIds];
      }

      $storeIds = array_unique($storeIds);

      if ($index = array_search(null, $storeIds)) {
          unset($storeIds[$index]);
          $nullCheck = true;
      }

      if ($this->_from || $this->_to) {
        $mainTable = $this->getTable($this->getTableByAggregationPeriod('daily'));
      } else {
        $mainTable = $this->getTable($this->getTableByAggregationPeriod('yearly'));
      }

      if ($nullCheck) {
          $select->where("$mainTable.store_id IN(?) OR $mainTable.store_id IS NULL", $storeIds);
      } else {
          $select->where("$mainTable.store_id IN(?)", $storeIds);
      }

      return $this;
  }

  // Rest of class...

}
```

And then set the preference in `code/Vendor/MagentoSales/etc/di.xml` (along with the relevant `module.xml`, `composer.json`, and `registration.php` files).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" type="Vendor\MagentoSales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection" />
</config>
```