# Magento 2 - Get only enabled products in a collection

Tags: magento2

I try to get a collection of configurable product but disabled product are showing up.here is my code

```
  $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $this->_productCollection = $this->_reportCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')             
                    ->addViewsCount()
                    ->setStoreId($currentStoreId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId)
                    ->addFilter('type_id','configurable' )
```

So I tried

```
 $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1) );
 $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
 $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
                            'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                        );
```

But none on them works, It return all product since it seems that status of disabled product is 1 also:

```
var_dump($_product->getStatus())
```

return 1 on disabled and enabled product

I tried to refresh cache `php bin/magento cache:flush`, remove everything  in  `var/generation`, also reindex `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but no luck.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Here is my complete class

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;


class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct{


    protected $_reportCollectionFactory;
    protected $_typeFilter;




     public function __construct(
        //parent
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface  $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,

        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $reportCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,

        array $data = []
    ) {


        $this->_reportCollectionFactory = $reportCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
    }

  protected function _getProductCollection($force_reload = false){
        if ($this->_productCollection === null|| $force_reload == true) {

                $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

                $this->_productCollection = $this->_reportCollectionFactory->create()

                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

                    ->addViewsCount()
                    ->setStoreId($currentStoreId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId)
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1)); 
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
                    //->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
                    ;

                if (!empty($this->_typeFilter)){
                    $this->_productCollection->addFilter('type_id',$this->_typeFilter );  
                }



        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
   }

    public function setTypeFilter($typeFilter = []){
        return $this->_typeFilter = $typeFilter; 
    }

    public function getFilteredCollection($typeFilter = []){
        $this->setTypeFilter($typeFilter); 
        return $this->_getProductCollection(true);
    }







}
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80179/magento-2-apply-visibility-and-status-filters-on-product-collection <--- You can try this one as reference maybe you can get something out of that thread. 

And also have you tried reindexing your site?

Comment: I tried that already, problem is the 'status' filter doesn't work,  it seems that every products got the status value to 1, instead of 2 for disabled

Comment: Hmmmm that seems to be a bug as per my research in magento 2. But I'm not really sure if it's a bug. What is the version of your current magento 2?

Comment: It's magento version 2.1.1

Comment: @pajouk please show your _constuct() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your store to **Default Store View*** in backend and disable the product. Then check it again with your code.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, Magento create an 'enable' variable for each store view and changing it from the  default view doesn't change the child view

Comment: In DB I have checked it is disabled(`having value 2`) but in front-end it shows `1`.Do I need to reindex it?

Comment: Yes. Reindex the product and then check.

Answer (score 8):

**For Only Enable and In stock product visibility,**

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct{

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface  $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory, 
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter,
    array $data = []
) {

    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_stockFilter = $stockFilter; 
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}
public function _getProductCollection(){
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        //only filter in stock product
        $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
        return $collection;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, since `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED` is the same as 1, it return all the products.  Somehow, disabled products seems to have 1 as status value

Comment: Remove var folder from root and Just try with above code. Its working fine for my case.

Comment: I did, still not working. In the catalog from the backend, there are noted as disabled, but on the frontend `$_product->getStatus()` return 1 for disabled product . So it look like cache issue or 'status' is not loaded somehow

Comment: please first do reindex and clear cache. Its working solutions.

Comment: I did that. I know it should work, that's why I post here. Also in your solution, Filters are missing `->addViewsCount()
                    ->setStoreId($currentStoreId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($currentStoreId)->addFilter('type_id',$this->_typeFilter )`

Answer (score 0):

For getting product collection with status enable

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    array $data = []
)
{

    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function _getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, disabled and enabled products still showing up