# Magento 2: Get collection of disabled products

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Following code isn't working to retreive disabled products even after adding respective filter:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
```

.....

```
 $childIds = array(1,2,3); //array of enabled and disabled product ids.
 $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=> $childIds))
            ->load();
```

Actual: $collection has all enabled products.

Expecting: $collection should have all disabled products from $productIds array.
Need help to find disabled products in $childIds array.
TIA

Comment: Please refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163706/magento-2-get-only-enabled-products-in-a-collection

Comment: I have seen his solution. but its not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **getItems()** instead of **load()**. And it's better to use the Service Contracts Layer instead of Collections.

Comment: I am sorry but it is not solving the problem. I would like to include **disabled** products in my collection. The solution given by you still giving me only enabled products.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below one,

```
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED, 'eq')->create();
$searchResults = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$disabledProducts = $searchResults->getItems();
```