# Get a product collection ignoring variations

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm trying to get a list of products filtered by categories, get all products from categories "Tees" plus all products from "watch" for example. The code:

```
$ids = ['16', '6'];
$productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $ids));

return $productCollection;
```

This works correctly, but it returns all variations of my configurable products, and I want just the main product, how can I get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get this, just applying a filter on visibility of products, I found the answer [in this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80179/magento-2-apply-visibility-and-status-filters-on-product-collection). The code:

First, we have to inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
)
{
     $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
}
```

And then in my select code:

```
$ids = ['16', '6'];
//$ids = ['16'];
$productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $ids));
$productCollection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
return $productCollection;
```

With this, I get only the head products of my configurable products.

Comment: The **$productCollection->setVisibility(...)** do all the magic.